# Creating a search and display feature for my project but can't get the results from database to display

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I am trying to create a search and display type of feature on my project, however, when I try to type something into the search bar nothing is being displayed, I would like to have an error message if there was no entries with said value but display the entries with said value. Below is my code and I will be very thankful with any suggestions and/or a solution to my problem, as I say, I am just a beginner coder.

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');
    if ($db->connect_error){
        die("Error: " . $db->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Quiz";
    if(isset($_GET['search'])){
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']));
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Quiz WHERE name = '$name'";
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Quizzes </title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "quiz.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class = "header">
    <h2> Quizzes </h2>
</div>

<form method = "GET" action = "">
    <div class = "input-group">
        <label>Search for a quiz: </label>
        <input type = "type" name = "name" placeholder = "search">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" name="search">
    </div>

      <?php
            while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
                echo $row['name'];
            }
        ?>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note: those look like real credentials. Please remember to change your password if they are.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how to connet to the database:

```
DEFINE('SERVER', '127.0.0.1');
DEFINE('PORT', '');
DEFINE('PSEUDO', 'root');
DEFINE('PWD', '');
DEFINE('DB_NAME', 'EEE');
function connectDB() {
static $db = null;
if ($db === null) {
    try {
        $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=". SERVER .";port=". PORT .";dbname=". DB_NAME, PSEUDO, PWD, $pdo_options);
        $db->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        throw $exc;
    }
}
return $db;
}
```

And When you make a sql query:

```
$db = connectDB();
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT lastname FROM user WHERE email LIKE ?");
$query->bindParam(1, $email);

if ($query->execute()) {
 //Data are in $tab
 $tab = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: so if I put both of these pieces of code in the same file that I have shown and get rid of my PHP code?

Comment: Yes, if you replace your php code by this one, but you need to adapt to your query and when the database return the result you need to display it(its' in $tab)

Comment: in the first part of the code do I leave server in and then in the bit after type the server i'm using in? sorry I'm just trying to get used to using PHP